# After using pyqtgraph's OpenGL to draw a 3D graph, how to obtain the absolute coordinates of the 3D world by clicking the mouse

Tags: python, pyqtgraph, pyopengl

After using pyqtgraph's OpenGL to draw a 3D graph, how to obtain the absolute coordinates of the 3D world by clicking the mouse.

I tried, but it was wrong

i got the wrong x,y,z

```py
import numpy as np
from OpenGL.GL import glReadPixels
from OpenGL.GLU import gluUnProject
from OpenGL.raw.GL.ARB.vertex_shader import GL_FLOAT
from OpenGL.raw.GL.VERSION.GL_1_0 import GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from pyqtgraph import opengl as gl, PlotWidget, LabelItem, InfiniteLine, SignalProxy
from pyqtgraph.opengl import GLViewWidget, MeshData, GLMeshItem
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.WGL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *


class GLView(GLViewWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        from stl import mesh
        # stl_mesh = mesh.Mesh.from_file('DeLorean.STL')
        self.coordinates = [0, 0, 0]


        self.grid_item = gl.GLGridItem()
        self.addItem(self.grid_item)
        x_axis_item = gl.GLLinePlotItem(pos=np.array([[0, 0, 0], [10, 0, 0]], dtype=np.float32),
                                        color=(1, 0, 0, 1),
                                        width=2)
        self.addItem(x_axis_item)

        y_axis_item = gl.GLLinePlotItem(pos=np.array([[0, 0, 0], [0, 10, 0]], dtype=np.float32),
                                        color=(0, 1, 0, 1),
                                        width=2)
        self.addItem(y_axis_item)

        z_axis_item = gl.GLLinePlotItem(pos=np.array([[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 10]], dtype=np.float32),
                                        color=(0, 0, 1, 1),
                                        width=2)
        self.addItem(z_axis_item)

        # points = stl_mesh.points.reshape(-1, 3)
        # faces = np.arange(points.shape[0]).reshape(-1, 3)
        #
        # mesh_data = MeshData(vertexes=points, faces=faces)
        # mesh = GLMeshItem(meshdata=mesh_data, smooth=False, drawFaces=False, drawEdges=True, edgeColor=(1, 1, 1, 1))
        # mesh.translate(-0.86,0,-0.5)
        # mesh.rotate(90,10,0,0)
        # mesh.scale(0.05,0.05,0.05)
        # self.addItem(mesh)




    def mousePressEvent(self, ev):

        if ev.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            pos = ev.pos()

            winX = pos.x()
            winY = pos.y()
            viewport = glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT)
            ori_v = self.getViewport()

            modelview = glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)
            ori_model = self.viewMatrix()
            matrix_array = np.array(ori_model.data(), dtype=np.float32)
            ori_model = matrix_array.reshape(4, 4)

            projection = glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX)
            ori_pro = self.projectionMatrix()
            ori_pro = np.array(ori_pro.data(), dtype=np.float32)
            ori_pro = ori_pro.reshape(4, 4)
            winY = viewport[3] - winY
            winZ = glReadPixels(winX, winY, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT)

            ori_model = ori_model.astype(np.float64)
            ori_pro = ori_pro.astype(np.float64)
            # ori_v = ori_v.astype(np.float64)
            # print(winX, winY, winZ, modelview, projection, viewport)
            x, y, z = gluUnProject(winX, winY, winZ, ori_model, ori_pro, ori_v)
            self.coordinates = [x, y, z]
            print(self.coordinates)
```

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QApplication

from single_graph import GLView


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQtGraph 3D Demo")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 900, 600)

        # 创建一个 QWidget 作为主窗口的中心部件
        self.centralWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        # 创建一个 QVBoxLayout 布局，并将其设置为 centralWidget 的布局
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.viewWidget = GLView()
        layout.addWidget(self.viewWidget)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    # stl_mesh = mesh.Mesh.from_file('DeLorean.STL')
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

After using pyqtgraph's OpenGL to draw a 3D graph, how to obtain the absolute coordinates of the 3D world by clicking the mouse.

I tried ,but it was wrong

i got the wrong x,y,z